# Como saber si un checkbox no esta seleccionado en Java

Tags: java

Yo sé que con "isSelected()" puedo saber si el checkbox esta seleccionado pero, me interesa saber si el checkbox no esta seleccionado.

Traté haciendo:

```
chckbxProvincial == null;
!chckbxProvincial.isSelected()
```

no me funciona.

Quiero saber si no esta seleccionado para mostrar un mensaje.

No puedo usar un ELSE ya que tengo muchos checkbox y quisiera validar esto en todos.

Alguna idea?.

Comment: La manera de saber si no esta seleccionado es esa amigo, !chckbxProvincial.isSelected(), pero el chckbxProvincial == null que tienes no se para que lo pones. if(!chcchckbxProvincial.isSelected()){//No esta seleccionado}

Comment: Hola, al principio no me estaba funcionando pero, ahora sí. El problema que tenía era de lógica, estaba usando || en lugar de && y por esa razón nunca entraba al primer if. Gracias hermano, gracias a ti he podido reflexionar esa parte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionado. Gracias a "Alexis Rodriguez".

La forma correcta de saber si un checkbox no esta seleccionado es:

```
!chckbx1.isSelected()
```